# User Selection (workbook and sheet name) then Copy and Paste

Tags: vba, excel, button

Is there a way to make it where user selects which sheet to copy from, after they opened file?

I'd like to do this because there may be multiple sheets with same format, but have different names.

Example:
Original workbook named **VSC** (Contains sheets **Compare**, **Plot**)

Secondary workbook named **SF** (Contains sheets **Results1**, **Results2**, **Results3**)

User clicks button on **VSC**, and file dialog opens, and user selects **SF** in a certain directory, then asks user to select which sheet to choose from - user chooses **Results2** sheet, copies the data (Range"B2:B5"), then pastes it back to **Compare**  sheet.

Would this be possible? I am not sure how to start.

Current code that asks user to select SF workbook:

```
Sub GetFilePath()
Dim objFSO as New FileSystemObject

Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With myFile
    .Title = "Choose File"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
FileSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
```

Comment: Do you he macro to open **SF** or will it already be open when the macro runs??

Comment: User will have to select the SF workbook, I updated my post with the file dialog part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach. You type in the sheet name. Adjust copy and paste ranges to suit.

```
Sub GetFilePath()

Dim objFSO As New FileSystemObject, w As String, wb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With myFile
    .Title = "Choose File"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
End With

w = InputBox("Enter sheet name")

If SheetExists(w) Then
    wb.Sheets(w).Range("B2:B5").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Compare").Range("A1").pastespecial xlvalues
Else
    MsgBox "Sheet not found"
End If

wb.Close False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function SheetExists(s As String) As Boolean

Dim x    
On Error GoTo NextSheet
x = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Name
SheetExists = True
Exit Function    
NextSheet:
    SheetExists = False    
End Function
```

Comment: Is there a forum I can look at about copy and pasting? The code you gave works, but I just want the value, and not paste the format

Comment: Look up pastespecial - I have amended the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your workbook open, you can enumerate the sheets by name and populate a pick list on a sheet in the VSC workbook...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach to your question. It is using a Timer  after opening the new Workbook to ask you every 10 seconds if you are on the sheet you want to copy from. If you answer "Yes" it will copy. If you answer "no" it will restart the 10 second timer.

```
Sub GetFilePath()
    Set MyFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With MyFile
        .Title = "Choose File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        FileSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    Set newWk = Workbooks.Open(FileSelected, , True)
    'Open Selected Workbook and check in 10 seconds for Selected Sheet Name
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "CheckForSheet"
End Sub
Private Sub CheckForSheet()
    Dim SheetName As String
    SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    answer = MsgBox("Is This the Sheet to copy from: " & SheetName & "?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Copy Data?")
    If answer = vbYes Then
        'ThisWorkbook is the workbook with the Macro/VBA code
        'ActiveWorkbook is the workbook where you are selecting the Sheet to copy from
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Range("B2:B5").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Compare").Range("C1:C4").PasteSpecial
    Else
        'Check Again in 10 Seconds
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "CheckForSheet"
    End If
End Sub
```